# Using Factory with DryIoc and getting object by string

Tags: vb.net, dryioc

I am just testing invertion control using DryIoc library. Please check above to get the picture.

I have that factory class:

```
 'FactoryConnections using IoC Dry
    Public Class FactoryConnections

        Private Shared ReadOnly Container As Container

        Shared Sub New()
            Container = New Container()
            With Container

                .Register(Of ISftp, Sftp)
                .Register(Of ISaop, Soap)

                '.Register(Of IFtp, Ftp)
                .Register(Of IFtp, Ftp)(serviceKey:= "some string value")
            End With
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function ResolveService(Of T As IProtocol)(value As Iprotocol) As T
            Return Container.Resolve(Of T)
        End Function
    End Class
```

Just shortly according to invertion:

```
A ->  Y  (A uses Y)
A -> Interface B -> Y (in this case A doesn't know about Y)
```

we can read my solution the same:

```
A -> IFtp -> Ftp
```

Therefore instead of getting directly object like: Ftp, Sftp or Soap code should ask factory to get one of them based on the interface therefore calling point doesn't know exactly what concrete object is using but it knows who implements that - that's at elast my understanding. Therefore i could ask calling them via interfaces. This is what i am trying to do however from string value (project related requirment).

```
Dim myProtocol As String = "IFtp"
```

And as mentioned having that i want to get proper object from my factory in this case i should get New instance of Ftp right?

*Note that parent interface for IFtp, ISoap, ISftp is IProtocol*

I was trying like this:

```
Dim myProtocol As String = "IFtp"
Dim itemprotocol As type = Type.GetType(myProtocol)
Dim realprotocolobject = FactoryConnections.ResolveService(TypeOf(itemprotocol))
```

and also tried like this:

```
Dim myProtocol As String = "IFtp"
Dim realprotocolobject = FactoryConnections.ResolveService(Of IProtocol)(myProtocol)
```

What's wrong, What am i doing wrong?

One more thing: what is the diffrence between those lines?
(just saw this serviceKey somwhere..)

```
.Register(Of IFtp, Ftp)
.Register(Of IFtp, Ftp)(serviceKey:= "some string value")
```

**Further discussionre reference:**

Factory class:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkQvbwpYPYoIh0IqruVthcndFyOM

UnitTestClass:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkQvbwpYPYoIh0G7iEfy427aJXXw

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write correct VB, so try to answer with C#. Hope it can be easily translated.

You may use `serviceKey` both in registration and resolve to identify the service from many of the same type, e.g. `IProtocol`.

```
container.Register<IProtocol, Ftp>(serviceKey: "ftp");
container.Register<IProtocol, Sftp>(serviceKey: "sftp");
```

Later:

```
var p = container.Resolve<IProtocol>(serviceKey: "sftp");
Assert.IsInstanceOf<Sftp>(p);
```

You may get all protocols with `ResolveMany` or by injecting an array or `IEnumerable` parameter.

```
var ps = container.ResolveMany<IProtocol>();
Assert.AreEqual(2, ps.Count());
```

Note that I did not specify `serviceKey` in `ResolveMany`.

### Injecting keyed dependency

There may be a case when you want deep down dependency to be resolved by key. Then when registering dependency consumer you may specify it like this:

```
container.Register<ProtocolUser>(
    made: Parameters.Of.Type<IProtocol>(serviceKey: "ftp"));
var pu = container.Resolve<ProtocolUser>();
Assert.IsInstanceOf<Ftp>(pu.Protocol);
```

There are also other approaches, e.g. using [requiredServiceType](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RequiredServiceType).

Here is example:

```
container.Register<IFtp, Ftp();
container.Register<ISftp, Sftp();
```

Let's assume that both `IFtp` and `ISftp` implement `IProtocol`. 
There are two ways to specify that you want `IFtp` for `IProtocol` dependency (without using service keys).

First option, when you register dependency consumer/holder:

```
 container.Register<ProtocolUser>(
    made: Parameters.Of.Type<IProtocol, IFtp>());
```

Second option, to specify globally per container, which will affect all dependencies of `IProtocol` type.

```
var specializedContainer = container.With(
    Parameters.Of.Type<IProtocol, IFtp>());
```

Comment: the problem here is i want to pass IFtp and get Ftp. I think in your case i give "Ftp" and will get Ftp.

Comment: besides i cannot just use:             Dim setCommand = FactoryConnections.ResolveService(Of IProtocol)(servicekey:="sftp") because from unittest project it says that serviceKey is not parameter of function ResolveService and for the pther ResolveMany it says its not a member of FactoryConnections

Comment: Don't understand. In a question you daid you need to select service by string "IFtp". Also `ResolveService` is your method. So just add the optional `serviceKey` parameter and pass it over to container Resolve.

Comment: I have added example of using required service type instead of string key.

Comment: Look at main post i made two pictures to ilustrate issue.

Comment: Look at link (in main post - further discussion reference) besides: UnitTestClass there is an error on picture when you click the link.

Comment: I saw the error, I just don't know what is mean. If it means that ResolveService does not have a parameter `serviceKey`, then that's true. Can you add the `serviceKey` parameter to ResolveService method? Who controlling FactoryConnections?

Comment: ResolveService is shown in main post should i change something there? Let me know what should i change because i am bit lost here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165327/discussion-between-arie-and-dadhi).